# Flutter - child widgets not rebuilding in tabBarView

Tags: flutter

I am unable to build the children Operations and Logistics widget in the following code. I have tried setState and valuelistenableBuilder, but nothing is working. Operations and Logistics store their own list (and some other data), when they are first built (init is called) they fetch the data from API.

````
final GlobalKey<OperationsState> operationsKey = GlobalKey();
final GlobalKey<LogisticsState> logisticsKey = GlobalKey();

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  _tabsList = [
      Tab(
        child: Text(
          'Operations',
          style: CustomAppTheme.tabHeading,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
      ),
      Tab(
        child: Text(
          'Logistics',
          style: CustomAppTheme.tabHeading,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
      ),
    ];


    // Operations and Logistics are stateful widget with their own state/data
    _tabBarViewList = [
      Tab(
        child: Operations(
          operationsKey: operationsKey,
          logisticsKey: logisticsKey,
        ),
      ),
      Tab(
        child: Logistics(),
      ),
    ];

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      initialIndex: 0,
      child: Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        floatingActionButton: ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: _showFloatingActionButton,
          builder: (_, showButton, child) {
            return showButton
                ? FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context)
                          .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                        return CreateRequest();
                      })).then((val) {
                        // on successfull request creation I am passing 'reload' to refresh the tabs
                       if (val == 'reload') {
                          // _refreshLeaves.value++;
                          setState(() {

                          });
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.add),
                    backgroundColor: CustomAppTheme.primaryColor,
                  )
                : Container();
          },
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(), // code omitted as not related to the question
        body: ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: _refreshLeaves,
          builder: (_, refresh, child) {
            return TabBarView(
                // controller: _tabController,
                children: _tabBarViewList);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it... instead of passing already initialized GlobalKey() I passed UniqueKey(). This updated the children correctly whenever setState() is called.